# rotating a CALayer in iOS 7 translates the layer randomly

Tags: ios, rotation, calayer

I'm trying to rotate an image layer by given angle, but it is showing a really weird behavior in iOS 7. It works as expected in iOS 8 and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the expected image (iOS 8 result). (45 degrees rotated)

[image: expected result]

This is what I get from iOS 7.

[image]

The arrow is supposed to have the same center as the image, but it moves to an unexpected position.

Here's my code. (initial translate and anchor point is to adjust the rotating center because the arrow image's rotation should not happen around the actual center of that image -- and even without these lines, it doesn't make any difference in iOS 7)

```
if (CATransform3DIsIdentity(self.compassImageView.layer.transform)) {
    self.compassImageView.layer.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(CATransform3DIdentity, 0, 5, 0);
}
self.compassImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 95 / 180.0);

NSString *zRotationKeyPath = @"transform.rotation.z";
[self.compassImageView.layer setValue:@(targetAngle * M_PI / 180.0) forKeyPath:zRotationKeyPath];
```

Thanks!